# I am all in one, guess what?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> 1. I am all in one,
> 2. I am part of Mozilla,
> 3. Part of the Olympic Games,
> 4. Although I am unwilling to work and would like to eat a hotdog,
> 5. Speed is the second part of all in one. (1)
> 6. Color which is not same as color of part of Mozilla  (2)

All the clue have one or two unique words which you have to find out from all points,

Combine and arrange those words and find out the thing which is "ALL in One."

(1) and (2) means it's related to that point.

Comment: cant stop thinking of Formula One racing

Comment: Great puzzle! I can't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADG has the right idea in his answer, but didn't fix all the words quite right.

> THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG.

1.I am all in one,

> The full sentence contains all the letters in the English alphabet.

2.I am part of Mozilla,

> **FOX** is part of "Firefox", owned by Mozilla.

3.Part of the Olympic Games,

> Jumping over things is a sport in the Olympic Games, so this gives us **JUMPS OVER**.

4.Although I am unwilling to work and would like to eat a hotdog,

> Unwilling to work means **LAZY**. Hotdog gives us **DOG**.

5.Speed is the second part of all in one. (1)

> The second word of the sentence is **QUICK**.

6.Color which is not same as color of part of Mozilla (2)

> **BROWN** is a colour, but not the colour of fire (as in Firefox - see 2).

Combining and arranging the words found (with a couple of extra "the"s), we get the sentence spoilered above.

Comment: Great.. good explanation.. :)

Comment: @randal'thor how's it different from my answer?

Comment: @ADG I caught the "lazy" clue and wrote a fuller explanation; other than that, it's pretty similar to yours. If I were the OP, I'd give you the tick (although I did think you were a bit rude to him in comments).

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Explanation

> All alphabets: All in one.
>
> Mozilla: Firefox: Fox.
>
> Olympic: Jumping.
>
> Hotdog: Dog.
>
> Speed: Quick.
>
> Color: Brown.

Comment: @CoDeMurDeRer resee? really?

Comment: Yes.. see you are closer but missing something..

Comment: Give ADG the correct answer if they have it. The sentence is commonly known to have all the letters of the alphabet in it.